# Vuetify2 vertical slider height not configurable

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to set a specific height for a vertical slider in vuetify2. I tried that via height="800px" and style="height:800px" but without the intended effect.

The box of my grid gets extended but the height of the slider does not change.

I use

```
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row>
    ...
    <v-col lg="2">
      <v-card class="pa-1" outlined tile>
        <v-slider min="1" max="180" v-model="angle" @input="setAngle" vertical style="height:800px"/>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  ...
</v-container>
```

and get the result in the screenshot - i.e. height does not change[image]

Solutions anyone or is that maybe due to version 2.0.x of vuetify 2?

Comment: Raised bug for vuetify 2 on https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no shortcut prop to set the height of a [`v-slider`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders).

However you can still use css to adjust the height of the slider, like the [vertical slider](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders#vertical-sliders) documentation recommends.

This should do the trick: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Turtlefight/pen/bGbrqmB)

**HTML**

```html
<v-slider min="1" max="180"  vertical class="large-slider" prepend-icon="mdi-axis-y-rotate-clockwise"/>
```

**CSS**

```css
.large-slider .v-slider {
  height: 800px;
}
```

If you're using [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with scoped styles, you need to use vue's [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) for this to work:

```html
<style scoped>
.large-slider >>> .v-slider {
  height: 800px;
}
</style>
```